# Flip numbers in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, actionscript-3, string

I have an issue with some Arabic text where I need to ***flip*** numbers inside a string. So this:

```
"Some text written in 1982 by someone with m0123456 or 12-to-13"
```

Should become:

```
"Some text written in 2891 by someone with m6543210 or 21-to-31"
```

A regex solution will be great. The more optimized for large strings the better.

Any hints?

Comment: maybe you should use regex to find the part of the string(numbers) then do `String reverse = new StringBuffer(string).
reverse().toString();`

Comment: Even though Arabic is written from right to left, the numbers (1234, not ١٢٣٤) are still written from left to right. (Shouldn't Flash be able to deal with RTL issues?)

Comment: @KennyTM I'm developing a custom text rendering solution which requires flipping numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
theText.replace(/\d+/g, function(s:String){ return s.split("").reverse().join(""); })
```

(Disclaimer: only tested for Javascript, not ActionScript.)

Comment: Perfect! I adjusted it a little bit for Flash (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @KennyTM! Your solution worked flawlessly (after some tweaks).

I just had to specify the type of the regexp pattern, and remove the strict argument type in line 3 (:String)

```
var theText = "Some text written in 1982 by someone with m0123456 or 12-to-13";
var pattern:RegExp = /\d+/g;
var result = theText.replace(pattern, function(s){ return s.split("").reverse().join("") })

trace(result);   //Some text written in 2891 by someone with m6543210 or 21-to-31
```

Comment: I don't understand why you had to make the changes you made... the code KennyTM provided should work perfectly for AS3 too.

Comment: The only thing that didn't work was the :String in the attribute. Just remove that and you're good to go.